# If for every sub-segment of $[a,b]$ exists $x$ so that $f(x)\le1$ prove that integral in that segment < $a-b$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been trying to solve this question:

> Let $f(x)$ be an integralable in segment $[a,b]$, and assume that for every subsegment to $[a,b]$, exists $x$ so that $f(x)\le 1$.
>
> Prove that $\int_a^bf(x)dx\le b-a$

I know that if for ALL points in the segment the assumption is true, but how do you go around "for every subsegment exists a point"?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use the definition of Riemann integral, or that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: How should I choose to create the subset of $x$'s? We don't know at which points $f(x)\le 1$.

Comment: At least you know they exist, **in every subintervals**